# Changing time zone after getting GMT time from database - MonetDB

Tags: java, jdbc, timezone, timestamp, monetdb

I have MonetDB database with table containing user table:

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
    birth_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

`birth_date` is saved in GMT without DST. (This is the default behavior of MonetDB). So I should change the `TimeZone` in my application. Here is my code:

```
Class.forName("nl.cwi.monetdb.jdbc.MonetDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:monetdb://localhost/online", "monetdb", "monetdb");      
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs;

rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user");
while (rs.next()) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tehran"));
    c.setTime(rs.getTimestamp("birth_date"));
    System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
}
```

But this code print the same `TIMESTAMP` in the database. Is this the wrong way to convert `TimeZone`? I'm using MonetDB version 11.9.5-20120516 on Debian 6 with openjdk 6. Here is the `monetdbd getall /home/dbfarm`:

```
dbfarm           /home/dbfarm/
status           monetdbd[4187] 1.6 (Apr2012-SP1) is serving this dbfarm
mserver          /usr/bin/mserver5
logfile          /home/dbfarm//merovingian.log
pidfile          /home/dbfarm//merovingian.pid
sockdir          /tmp
port             50000
exittimeout      60
forward          proxy
discovery        yes
discoveryttl     600
control          yes
passphrase       {SHA512}ba3253876aed6bc22d4a6ff53d8406c6ad864195ed144ab5c87621b6c233b548baeae6956df346ec8c17f5ea10f35ee3cbc514797ed7ddd3145464e2a0bab413
mapisock         /tmp/.s.monetdb.50000
controlsock      /tmp/.s.merovingian.50000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I got the answer.

MonetDB runs in `GMT` by default and because `Asia/Tehran` was not available in database configuration so I need to convert time to `Asia/Tehran` time zone in my application. JVM takes its default `TimeZone` from OS and my OS was set to `Asia/Tehran`. So the program runs in `Asia/Tehran` by default and changing it to 'Asia/Tehran` again in code doesn't make any benefit. what I did was this:

1. change the default `TimeZone` of JVM to `UTC` when application starts.
2. retrieve record from database
3. change `TimeZone` to `Asia/Tehran`

Here is code:

```
/* Change the default TimeZone of JVM */
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); 
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
Class.forName("nl.cwi.monetdb.jdbc.MonetDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:monetdb://localhost/online", "monetdb", "monetdb");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs;
rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user");
/* In each iteration:
 * 1. set TimeZone to UTC
 * 2. fetch record
 * 3. convert to Asia/Tehran and so on ... */
while (rs.next()) {
    c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    c.setTime(rs.getTimestamp("birth_date"));
    System.out.println(c); /* This is original values in the database */
    c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tehran"));
    System.out.println(c); /* This is the values I'm looking for */
}
```

Note that without `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));` this won't work. becuase JDBC has connected to database and converted the time to the default `TimeZone` of the JVM (which is `Asia/Tehran` in this case) before you can do any conversion.

Answer (score 1):

How are you determining the time as returned from the monetdb?

I used the following code, which uses a `Date`, rather than an `java.sql.Timestamp`, and it appropriately converts from one timezone to another, so is it possible that something is translating the time from UTC to the localtime for you automatically?

```
    Date d = new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tehran"));
    c.setTime(d);
    System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

**Edit** If your java is badly configured, trying to get the timezone can fail; yielding the output in the same timezone as GMT, so you should always make sure that you're getting the correct timezone

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tehran");
System.out.println(tz.toString());
```

Displays `sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Tehran",offset=12600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=100,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Asia/Tehran,offset=12600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=1,startMonth=2,startDay=21,startDayOfWeek=0,startTime=0,startTimeMode=0,endMode=1,endMonth=8,endDay=21,endDayOfWeek=0,endTime=0,endTimeMode=0]]` for me; while:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/fred");
System.out.println(tz.toString());
```

Displays `sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]`

Comment: The problem is times don't change. records in database are the same after converting timezone in the application.

Comment: Is it possible that your instance of java is not able to determine the Asia/Tehran timezone? i.e. what does something like: `TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tehran"); System.out.println(tz.toString());` output?

Comment: `TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tehran"); System.out.println(tz.toString());` works fine. and prints `Asia/Tehran`. Check my answer.